# MyBatis delete-insert-update in one query

Tags: java, sql-server, mybatis

I want to perform 3 operations in the single mapping of mybatis mapper:

1) Delete from table X

2) insert into table X

3) update into table Y

is it possible to do so, if yes, then how?
if not, then what is the most performant way to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

a mapper can execute multi sql. it depends how the jdbc connection settings.